# System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("emailAddress") Doesn't Check For Valid Email

Tags: powershell

How can you check for a valid email address in Powershell?

I've googled this and most people say to use `$toadr = new-object net.mail.mailaddress($to)` with a try/catch.

However this doesn't check for .com etc at the end of the email.

Eg. `$toadr = new-object net.mail.mailaddress("test@mailcom")`

doesn't throw an exception even though there is no dot before com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using a regular expression.

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

```
$EmailRegex = '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$';
if ('test@mailcom' -match $EmailRegex) {
    # Matched
}
else {
    # Did not match
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not always possible to know whether an email address is valid on just analyzing the format of the string itself. `test@mailcom` may infact be a valid email-address (you wouldn't know without a DNS query), and so `MailAddress` cannot presume it's invalid.

As some of the popular email regex validators actually invalidate some valid email addresses, I would not recommend going beyond `MailAddress` for validation.